Are you more likely to be accepted to a conference that is being held in your university?
My university is hosting an international conference in my field. I would like to present at the conference. I have recently co-authored (along with my supervisor) a research paper that will soon be submitted to a journal for review. This paper would suit the conference well. I am still an undergrad so I'm not entirely sure how conferences work.

Would my affiliation to the host university have any impact on the application?
Would my supervisor be more likely to allow me to submit an abstract for the conference given that I wouldn't need accommodation funding?
I have worked with some of the committee members, is it still okay for me to submit an abstract?


You might be interested: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/171071/does-giving-a-good-conference-talk-affect-the-acceptance-of-future-submissions

Are conferences publications venues in your field or not? This is an important distinction and some answers may silently assume one or the other and thus not applicable to you. For example, in all fields I ever was in, I never heard of anybody having an abstract rejected from a conference. The main decision by the committee is whether something should be upgraded from poster to talk.

@Wrzlprmft Perhaps we need two [tag:conference] tags that would force the asker to identify their kind of conference. The only thing is I lack a name for either kind.

@AzorAhai: That would only work if we had no neutral conference tag, but then what to do with all that questions about conferences that apply to either kind?

@Wrzlprmft Fair point, how many of those are there?

@AzorAhai: Let’s continue this discussion in the Ivory Tower, since it has little to do with this question.

The answer depends on how each particular conference is organised. However, it is not unusual for local students to become a proportionally larger group compared with international visitors. This can be explained by several factors:

International conferences are normally organised at locations, which have historical ties to the topic of the conference, for example, at a University that hosts a strong team or a prominent world-class professor. Their students are familiar with the research of their supervisors, and as such, do research that matches the topic of the conference. Hence, local students have a better chance to be a good match as speakers for the conference.

Arranging a "short track" or "light-touch" approach for local participants can be seen as an informal "reward" for the hard work of the local organising committee

Local participants do not require budgets for travel and accommodation, which makes it easier for them to apply locally



Certainly you can submit an abstract. Many of us know and have worked with committee members of conferences.
You will need to ask your advisor, but (IMO) only if funding is needed. I don't believe an advisor should block a submission. You need approval of all authors, as usual.
Ideally, your affiliation will have no bearing on the case. It would be improper (again, IMO) for the committee to advantage or disadvantage anyone because of such things. The focus should be on the paper, not the author. I can't promise everyone shares that opinion, of course, nor that everyone behaves ethically, but in almost all cases committee membership implies some standing and prior ethical practice.
Edited to add: If any of the authors, especially the supervisor when an author, may have plans for the paper that a conference talk would interfere with. In particular, appearing in a conference might (some fields/situations) make a later journal publication impossible.

In my fields, the advisor would be an author on the abstract, and their approval would be needed.

All authors are always needed, advisor or not, @AzorAhai-him-, the OP described authorship in the singular, however.

I updated my post to clarify this - I am the first named co-author on the paper with my supervisor being last which is common in our field. I'm somewhat worried that asking my supervisor whether I could submit the abstract would be overly ambitious/eager. Would it be a reasonable suggestion for me to make as at the end of the day I am the student in this.

I think it is reasonable. Ambitious is a good thing. The paper needs to be ready for prime time, of course, and a conference submission needs to not be a problem for a later journal submission. Talk it over about the best way to proceed.

@jim_athon Saying "hey, could we submit an abstract to this" is usually well-received by supervisors, and pretty much the worst outcome would be your supervisor saying "no, we don't have money/full paper won't be ready by then/the research needs to mature more/etc." That is, you don't really have anything to lose by asking, and potentially lots to gain.



Would my affiliation to the host university have any impact on the application?


Most likely not. Conferences usually just look for speakers and abstracts that provide the greatest scientific value. But as @Buffy said, one cannot be sure about such things, and there is a chance it will make a slight difference.


Would my supervisor be more likely to allow me to submit an abstract for the conference given that I wouldn't need accommodation funding?


Yes, all other things equal, supervisors prefer to spend less money than more money. Any good advisor will seize on such a conference being held locally as a great (and cheap!) opportunity for their students to gain good experience, get their name and work out there, network with people from the field etc.


I have worked with some of the committee members, is it still okay for me to submit an abstract?


Yes, conferences generally have mechanisms to avoid conflicts of interest. No one wants to disadvantage people and prevent them from sharing their scientific knowledge just because they happen to have worked with some of the committee members. What will likely happen is that the conflicted committee members will have to recuse themselves from participating in the review of your abstract and/or discussions about whether to accept it. But you will still get fair consideration. It's also possible that the relationship you have with them will not be considered sufficiently significant to be classified as a conflict of interest, in which case this will simply not be an issue.
What I said above holds generically, but specific conferences may have specific policies that pertain to situations of this type (and which may approach the issue differently than this generic approach). So make sure to read any guidelines on the conference website before you submit your abstract.

In smaller fields it might be completely impossible to not know the committee members after a few years. I don't know if there is a special procedure for such cases, but these conferences are usually not the type that reject many abstracts.
